# Is there an easy way of migrating from Amazon Redshift to Microsoft Azure Data Warehouse?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-devops

I want to migrate from Amazon Redshift to Microsoft Azure. Is there an easy way of doing this copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to get data into redshift.
But even inside amazon there's only one way getting data out of redshift:

unload to s3

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html

On the other hand microsoft appears to provide a connector
For migrating:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-amazon-redshift